# Ember - Get values between Parent and Child views

Tags: ember.js

I have a ParentView and a childView which is nested within the parent. There are some variables in both parent and child view instances.

Now I need to get the values between parentView and childView.

My Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
    {{view App.PreviewView}}
</script>
```

Parent View:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="previewdiv">
    <div> Preview Div </div>
    <div  {{action 'getChildValue' target='view'}}>Get Child Value </div>
    {{view App.ChildpreviewView }}
</script>
```

Child View:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="childpreviewdiv">
    <div> Child Preview Div </div>
    <div  {{action 'getParentValue' target='view'}}>Get Parent Value </div>
</script>
```

App.js:

```
App.PreviewView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'previewdiv',
    tempParentValue: true,
    actions: {
        getChildValue: function(){
            // How to get "tempChildValue" here.
        }
    }
});

App.ChildpreviewView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'childpreviewdiv',
    tempChildValue: true,
    actions: {
        getParentValue: function() {
            // How to get "tempParentValue" here.
        }
   }
});
```

JSBIN [Link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ximezi/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Edited your JSBIN

http://jsbin.com/wihowu/2/edit

To access parentview you simply type :

```
this.get('parentView');
```

To access all childviews :

```
this._childViews
```

You could access only needed childView

```
var self = this;
this._childViews.forEach(function(childView){ 
     if(childView.get("templateName") === "childpreviewdiv") { 
        self.set('wantedChildView', childView); 
     } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it good practice to use "_childViews" (the underscore method), in our development code, because usually the "_methods" are used within the framework code. Generally it is not advisable to use "_methods" in development. Please correct me if I am wrong.